# Update a line chart's colour after every interval

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I have a line chart in React using the [Chart.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart.js) library. It is updating data to it every given interval, and displaying the colour of the last segment as orange and the rest of the segment as green.

When the chart updates, the previous segment remains orange and the new segment becomes green, which corrects when I recompile. Here is the code:

```
 const updateChartData=() => {
    setChartData((prevData) => {
      const currentLabels = [...prevData.labels];
      const currentData = [...prevData.datasets[0].data];

      // Add the new data point and remove the oldest one
      if(currentLabels.length !== 8) {
        const predictedPrice = getRandomPrice(100, 250);
        currentLabels.push(getTimeLabel(currentLabels.length + 9, 0));
        currentData.push(predictedPrice);
      }

      return {
        ...prevData,
        labels: currentLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            ...prevData.datasets[0],
            data: currentData,
            borderColor: "rgba(0,128,0,1)",
            segment: {
              borderColor: (ctx) =>
              lastSegment(ctx, "rgba(255, 165, 0, 1)") || "rgba(0,128,0,1)"
          },


          }],
      };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(updateChartData, 1000);
    return () => {
       clearInterval(interval)
      };
  }, []);
```

I want to update the colour with the interval, on the go.

Comment: Is "`const updateChartData=()`" a valid construct (not a rhetorical question)?